# onClick Listener for CursorAdapter

Tags: android

I created a customized CursorAdapter and want to select a list item, in order to start an action in onOptionsItemSelected.

Creating List View:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate called");
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Log.d(TAG, "create DatabaseOpenHelper");
    DatabaseOpenHandler helper = new DatabaseOpenHandler(this);

    Log.d(TAG, "get writeable database access");
    database = helper.getWritableDatabase();

    Log.d(TAG, "create Cursor for database access");
    Cursor data = database.query(DatabaseConstants.TABLE_NOTES, fields,
            null, null, null, null, null);

    Log.d(TAG, "set NoteCursorAdapeter");
    setListAdapter(new NoteCursorAdapter(this, data));  
}
```

onOptionItemSelected:

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onOptionItemSelected called");
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.conference_note_menu_new:
        Toast.makeText(this, "Es sind keine Einstellungen verfügbar",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return true;

    case R.id.conference_note_menu_edit:
        Toast.makeText(this, "Es sind keine Einstellungen verfügbar",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return true;

    case R.id.conference_note_menu_delete:
        Toast.makeText(this, "Es sind keine Einstellungen verfügbar",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return true;

    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Can't find any useful information on the internet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

onOptionItemSelected is for menu. you need set onItemClickListener for your ListView like this:

```
getListView().setOnItemClickListener(this);
```

and implements:

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the below line for item click listerner:;

```
public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View v, int position, long id) {
}
```

because

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
}
```

is for menu item selection

Answer (score 2):

this works for me:

```
       list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use OnLongClickListener() to populate a menu and then use your code to start your action on the selected item.